# How do I assess a ARIMA model?

Tags: r, time-series, model-selection

I am doing time series analysis. I used `auto.arima` to do model selection. The forecasting confidence interval seems really big on the plot. The residual plot seems OK. Am I missing something important? How do I assess if this one is a good model?

[image: residual plot]

[image: forecast plot]

Comment: It appears to my eyes that your residuals are clearly not a random process . At a minimum there are anomalies and a probable change in error variance at at least 1 point in time. Confidence limits are based upon both the psi weights and the error variance. If you post your data I am guessing there is a better model with resulting smaller error variance yielding possibly (probably !) tighter forecast confidence limits .

Comment: At a guess these are monthly data with some seasonality. It follows that plotting data and residuals against month of year is not only a good idea, it's essential to assess how well the model does in capturing that aspect as compared with others. See also cycle plots. e.g. https://www.perceptualedge.com/articles/guests/intro_to_cycle_plots.pdf and its references

Comment: It's surprisingly common that people won't plot observed vs estimated (fitted), sometimes called a calibration plot. Clearly it won't tell you when the biggest (smallest) errors occur but it shows (lack of) fit in a way that a time series plot doesn't always show well. Similarly, plot residual vs estimated.